# Error in seq.int(from, to, length.out = n) : 'from' must be a finite number , anyone can help me?

Tags: r

this is my code, and i am using both ggplot2 and reconplots:

```r
library(ggplot2)
demanda<- function(q) (100-q/10)
oferta<- function(q) (q/4)
x_range <- 1:500
curve_intersection<- curve(demanda, oferta, empirical=FALSE,
                           domain=c(min(x_range),max(x_range)))
curve_intersection
ggplot() +
    stat_function(aes(x_range)),color= "green",size=1,fun=demanda) +
    stat_function(aes(x_range)),color= "red",size=1,fun=oferta) +
    geom_vline(xintercept =curve_intersection$x,linetype= "doted" ) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = curve_intersection$y,linetype="doted") +
    theme_classic()
```

Answer (score 0):

I did research on `reconPlots` package through their [GitHub](https://github.com/andrewheiss/reconPlots), and here's my solution

Install and load the package

```r
library(devtools)
install_github("andrewheiss/reconPlots")
library(reconPlots)
```

I tried to follow the example from their GitHub and found out the example doesn't work. So I fixed some codes, and here's the result

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(reconPlots)

demanda <- function(q) (100-q/10)
oferta <- function(q) (q/4)
x_range <- 1:500
curve_intersection <- curve_intersect(demanda, oferta, empirical=FALSE, domain=c(min(x_range),max(x_range)))

ggplot(data.frame(x_range), aes(x_range)) +
  stat_function(color= "green", size=1, fun = demanda) +
  stat_function(color= "red", size=1, fun = oferta) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = curve_intersection$x, linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = curve_intersection$y, linetype = "dotted") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

**Note** that the `curve_intersect` function came from the `reconPlots` package, and it's different from `curve` function as in the `graphics` package in R

Answer (score 0):

You must have read the example from the [Github readme](https://github.com/andrewheiss/reconPlots). They give you the **wrong** code on their github readme. To fix the issues, you need to do this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(reconPlots)
demanda<- function(q) (100-q/10)
oferta<- function(q) (q/4)
x_range <- 1:500
curve_intersection<- curve_intersect(demanda, oferta, empirical=FALSE,
                           domain=c(min(x_range),max(x_range)))
ggplot() +
    stat_function( color = "green", size = 1, fun = demanda) +
    stat_function( color = "red", size = 1, fun = oferta) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = curve_intersection$x, linetype = "dotted") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = curve_intersection$y, linetype = "dotted") +
    theme_classic()+
    xlim(0, max(x_range))
```